# Different implementation of subsetting in a loop

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a problem relating to subsetting.

Basically I have a dataset. This toy dataset is a good small example:

`df<- data.frame(year = c(1980:2019), randnorm = rnorm(40, 0, 1), count1 = rpois(40, 18),
                lograndnorm=(rlnorm(40, 3, 2)))`

For each value of year between 2000 and 2019, I want to remove each years observation, and output a subset of the total df data excluding a year. I then want to take the year removed and enter it into a model, and use the remainder of the data to train the model.

For example, subset_ex2010 might be excluding 2010. Therefore, all data except for where year= 2010 goes into subset_ex2010 , and I can then use that data to predict 2010.

Once those parameters are entered into the model, the output is saved (after the model has run) and the loop does the next year, that is, removes 2009 from the full df dataframe and subsets the remainder.

I've tried:

```
for(i in 2000:2019){
  subset_excl_[i] <- subset(df, year<i | year>i] )
  subset_of_[i] <- subset(df, year==i] )
  lmmod[i] <- lm(count1 ~ randnorm + lograndnorm, data=subset_excl_[i])
  distPred[i] <- predict(lmmod[i], subset_of_[i]) 
}
```

and,

```
    for(i in 2000:2019){
  subset_excl_[i]  <- [df$year-i]
  subset_of_[i] <- subset(df, year==i] )
  lmmod[i] <- lm(count1 ~ randnorm + lograndnorm, data=subset_excl_[i])
  distPred[i] <- predict(lmmod[i], subset_of_[i]) 
}
```

but both fall over. Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know linear programming.  But. In both your blocks of code

```
lmmod[i] <- lm(count1 ~ randnorm + lograndnorm, data=subset_excl_[i])
distPred[i] <- predict(lmMod[i], subset_of_[i])
```

You're referring to both `lmmod` and `lmMod`.  R is case-sensitive.

If that alone doesn't fix it - put a `broswer()` call in the head of the loop and single step til you find where it's blowing up.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but the code is breaking down before it gets to the linear model part. It's something to do with bracketing I think?